# AngularJS - Form changed to invalid when custom directive is inserted

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to implement an asynchronous validation by using a custom directive.

This is the directive

```
moduloArea.directive('uniqueName', function($http, $q) {
    return {
        require : 'ngModel',
        link: function($scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            ngModel.$asyncValidators.nombre = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
                return $http.get('/checkUsernameAvailability/'+viewValue).then(
                    function(response) {
                        if (!response.data.validUsername) {
                            return $q.reject(response.data.errorMessage);
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                );
            };
        }
    }; 
});
```

The result in console

[image: console result when the username is typed]

As you can see when the *root* username is typed the return is an JSON object because this username is already taken.

But in the HTML the form in $invalid when the directive unique-name is inserted.

```
<form name="registerUsernameForm" novalidate="novalidate">
    <input type="text" name="username" data-ng-model="person.userName" data-unique-name="" required="required"/>
    <span data-ng-show="registerUsernameForm.username.$error.uniqueName">This username is already taken.</span>        
    <button type="submit" data-ng-disabled="registerUsernameForm.$invalid || registerUsernameForm.$pending" data-ng-click="registerPerson(person)"> Save Person </button>
</form>
```

I'm using the data-unique-name="" (**=""**) because if I don't then thymeleaf generate the following error:

> Attribute name "data-unique-name" associated with an element type
>   "input" must be followed by the ' = ' character.

What do you think can be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are validating **nombre** not **uniqueName**. For this reason, uniqueName is still stay invalid.

```
 moduloArea.directive('uniqueName', function($http, $q) {
    return {
        require : 'ngModel',
        link: function($scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            ngModel.$asyncValidators.uniqueName= function(modelValue, viewValue) {
                 var value = modelValue || viewValue;
                return $http.get('/checkUsernameAvailability/'+value ).then(
                    function resolved(response) {
                        if (response.data && !response.data.validUsername) {
                            return $q.reject(response.data.errorMessage);
                        }
                        return true;
                    }, function rejected() {
                      //username does not exist, therefore this validation passes
                      return true;
 }
                );
            };
        }
    }; 
});
```

Comment: Thanks man, would you explain this directive to me like I'm 8. I really noob with this and I'm lost from 'function resolved(response)' onwards.

Comment: resolved is just a name for clearing the code. You can set what you want. $http promise basicaly have 2 callback. first is success and second can be seen an error. When rest api return 2XX status, this means it is success. 4XX are client errors, 5XX are server errors. Namely you can throw an error if name does not exist. This means validation success.